# WPF Share and Update lists between different windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a scheduler in WPF. I have a central static list in main window, which is initialized on load by a backgroundworker. There also is a dispatchtimer in mainwindow, whose interval is recalculated everytime the list changes.

```
public static List<ListViewcls> TODOdatalst = null;
public static void RefreshdblList()
{
    if (ApplicationState.GetValue<bool>("dbDetected"))
    {
        TODOdatalst = DataAccess.ReadAllTODODataFromDataBase();
        InitialiseDailyReminders();
    }
}
```

Now there is another window which contains a listview which is bound to an observable collection, which is derived from the static list in mainwindow. whenever an item is added, updated or deleted from the list, the list in both the windows is manually refreshed via static functions.

```
private static readonly ObservableCollection<ListViewcls> TO_DOViewlst = new ObservableCollection<ListViewcls>();
public void RefreshView()
{
    MainWindow.RefreshdblList();
    if (MainWindow.TODOdatalst != null)
        InitialiseListView(MainWindow.TODOdatalst);
    else
        InitialiseListView(DataAccess.ReadAllTODODataFromDataBase());
}
```

so is this approach proper ?? It works for now but suppose in the future, i have one more window which will also access the list but then i will be managing the refresh of data between 3 windows....that does not figure right. Anyone can suggest some better way, that i can keep a central repository and whenever it is updated all other lists get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one uses MVVM there is an option to use one ViewModel (the class which acquires and holds the data which is used as Data Contexts for a window/page(s)) between multiple windows and this scenario is common.

I would opt to share the instantiated ViewModel (or class which houses your data) between all windows and pass it in during window creation to have the window/page's data context bound to that one VM. That way the satellite window(s) are using the same data as the main and not having to do any update tricks as shown. Plus any new windows simply bind to the observable collection which everyone else is binding to.

Comment: but the original list is well "a List" and for listview, i need observablecollection, so will i be able to use both or will there be any issues ?? I am not familiar with mvvm....googling it

Comment: @EternallyCurious Do you really need to use two different types to store the same data? OmegaMan's approach is the standard one. Move your data to a new ViewModel and share it between the windows ViewModels.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz: you tell me, i need the list to schedule the alerts and the observable collection to make the listview refresh automatically(in crude terms).....how should i go about ??

Comment: @EternallyCurious Unless you really need IList specific methods I'd go for the ObservableCollection. Even if you are using IList specific methods I'd find a reasonable workaround for it.

Comment: @EternallyCurious The list in main-window is not something static. It also supports item manipulation and needs to show the result of the manipulation. The only difference is that it doesn't manipulate the item directly but from the manipulation result of your sub-window. So it is ok to use a viewmodel with an ObservableCollection to share the data.

Comment: @EternallyCurious The Observable collection is what you want to use because any changes to the list (an addition or removal) will be passed on to the consumers of the list. If your list is not going to change in such a fashion, you can bind to directly to the list as long as the list observes a property notification change via INotifyProperty change on your class or the class as a defacto ViewModel.